# Azure Mobile Schedular APNS dosen't send push

Tags: apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

I have azure mobile server and i want push notification using scheduler job, 
But when i run for testing it fires an error.

Can any one guide me what is problem and solution ?

**Shedular Script:**

```
        function push() {                       
            setTimeout(function() {
                push.apns.send("XXXXXXdeviceTokenXXXXX", {
                    alert: "Toast: ", badge: 8            
                },{
                    error : function(err) {
                        console.log('error on 123.');
                    }
                });
            }, 2500);    
        }
```

**ERROR Code:**

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined at Object._onTimeout
>   (:8:19) [external code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining your function name as `push`, you're overriding the global [`push` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554217.aspx), which contains the `apns` member with a `send` function. Try defining the function in your script with a different name.